# aspose word add style doesn't work

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I add a style in doc but if style font Name is Mounted on word It does not work!!!
my font is a PersianFont

```
 Document doc = new Document();
     DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);     
     Aspose.Words.Style style = doc.Styles.Add(StyleType.Paragraph, "newStyle");
     style.IsQuickStyle = true;
     style.Font.Size = 24;
      style.Font.Name = "B Mitra";


 builder.ParagraphFormat.Style = style;  
    builder.Writeln("سلام");
```

Comment: Please try [latest version of Aspose.Words for .NET i.e. 17.12](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/). Also, please make sure that the font is installed on the machine where you are saving Document to PDF. In case the problem still remains, please ZIP and Upload your **Font file** and Aspose.Words' generated **PDF** to Dropbox and share the download link here for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document doc = new Document();
     DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);     
     Aspose.Words.Style style = doc.Styles.Add(StyleType.Paragraph, "newStyle");
     style.IsQuickStyle = true;
     style.Font.Size = 24;
     style.Font.SizeBi= 24;
     style.Font.Name = "B Mitra";
     style.Font.NameBi= "B Mitra";

 builder.ParagraphFormat.Style = style;  
    builder.Writeln("سلام");
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! For future readers of this post, the trick was to set the Bidrectional font properties *NameBi/SizeBi* .